# selenium webdriver not show dropdown list like a real browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium webdriver to fetch some contents from a URL, but I found the following error:
[This picture show the dropdown list, I got the url content through the real browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbQLn.png)

[This picture not show the dropdown list, I got the url content through the selenium webdriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWuIA.png)

I did not know why, please help me. Thank you very much.
This is my code:

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("myurl")

Comment: the reason is because, selenium driver every time launches  the browser with new profile(this profile doesnt linked with any of your other accounts like gmail or fb) but in real browser, it would have linked with some sort of accounts and based on that there might me different in the ads that we see or some similar kind of stuff.

Comment: @santhosh kumar Thank you. Is there some solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because, selenium driver every time launches the browser with new profile(this profile doesnt linked with any of your other accounts like gmail or fb) but in real browser, it would have linked with some sort of accounts and based on that there might me different in the ads that we see or some similar kind of stuff. To overcome this we can initiate our browser with the default profile that our real browser uses. Below code might give you some idea.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

To find path to your chrome profile data you need to type `chrome://version/` into address bar . For ex. mine is displayed as `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`, to use it in the script I had to exclude `\Default\` so we end up with only `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`.

Also if you want to have separate profile just for selenium: replace the path with any other path and if it doesn't exist on start up chrome will create new profile and directory for it.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you!